# ImageView animation with AdMob

Tags: android, animation, imageview, admob

I have a problem in my ImageView animation when integrate admob. If i don't integrate AdMob my ImageView animation runs correctly but if i do it, during the animation (the image moves left-right like a vibration) the ImageView looks like this:

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_8977435imagen.png

Black dots appear on the ImageView. I don't know why does that happen. can somebody help me?Thanks

EDIT:

Animation.xml

`<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromDegrees="-5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="4"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="5" />`

In my xml i have an empty RelativeLayout and i add squares programmatically. In this code is where i check the squares and call the animation.

Code:

```
for (int j = 1; j < filas+1; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < columnas; i++) {
            String btnid = String.valueOf(j)+String.valueOf(i+1);
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(btnid, "id", getPackageName());
            ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
            if(opc==0)
                im.setEnabled(false);
            else if(opc==1)
                im.setEnabled(true);
            else{
                if(im.getTag()!=null && im.getTag().equals("marcada")){
                    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.cuadrado_marcado);
                    im.setEnabled(false);
                }else if(im.getTag()!=null && im.getTag().equals("error")){
                    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.cuadrado_cruz);
                    im.setEnabled(false);
                    im.startAnimation(animVibrar);
                    if(Vibracion==true){
                        // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        // Vibrate for 400 milliseconds
                        v.vibrate(200);
                    }
                }else{
                    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.cuadrado);
                    im.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your xml

Comment: can u post your xml and animation code?

Comment: Everything works fine until i put ads and the black dots appears. In fact also occurs with a flip animation i have. I don't know if its because ads animation interfering with mine...

Comment: I have tested on different devices and black dots only appears in my Nexus 5, I don't know why :(

Comment: @jose19589 have you solved this issue? Having almost the same on Nexus 5

Comment: @Divers I found the problem but I couldn't solve it. It's not due to device, It´s by the Android version 4.4... In the other Android versions there is not problem and it occurs when you make a rotation animation and there are ads. If you make a lateral animation there is no problem but in my example yes. I solved it by changing my animation for another lateral animation (left-right) to obtain the vibration effect.

Comment: @Jose19589 Funny, I finished with same solution.

Comment: I too had hte same problem and I got my answer from [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166636/distorted-ui-onreceive-of-admob-ads