# Distorted UI onReceive of Admob Ads

Tags: android, animation, user-interface, admob, distortion

[image: distorted image]

The android UI gets distorted whenever the admob ads show up. And this happens on screens, which have some animations playing. On this screen I have a button animating with android:repeatCount="infinite".

I have observed this behavior since I have changed the admob Ad Id to the new Admob ID (after migrating to new Admob). Please help!!

Comment: You are going to need to show your layout plus your code.

Comment: I have applied rotationY for the linearlayout containing the buttons. Apart from that the layout design is pretty normal.

Answer (score 4):

This is an open issue reported to android issue tracker check

*Rendering glitch on View since Android 4.4.3.*
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70914

As a workaround which I also have in my apps is setting a layertype

```
yourView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

or

```
 yourView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

In my testing both solved the issue. You may need to add checks for android version as [setLayerType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType(int,%20android.graphics.Paint)) was added in API 11 if you are supporting apps all the way to GingerBread

Answer (score 0):

Go to  **Androidmanifest**  file and add the below line of code, it will work

> ```
> <application
>              android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
>          <activity 
>                    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
>          </activity> 
> </application>
> ```