# Rotated Button (anim) disappears after Banner Ad appears

Tags: android-layout, admob, android-animation, android-4.4-kitkat, asus

I have a button in the center of my screen, a spinner and a banner ad at the bottom. The app works perfectly on any phone that I've tried and also works fine in a galaxy 10.1 tablet. The button acts like a compass so I rotate it as the device moves. I load it on to an ASUS MeMo Pad 7" 800 x 1280 and it works great until the adMob banner shows up.  At that point, the button appears to get overlayed and go invisible. Occasionally when the compas makes an adjustment to its rotation, the button flickers back - on/off.

This app works on 5.1, 4.4.2 and passes the app store prelaunch tests. I've used the virtual device in Studio using Nexus 7 (800 x 1280) with 4.4.4 and it works. I can't determine if there is something different in the ASUS tablet or a bug in 4.4.4.

My layout looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/point"
                tools:context=".MainPlay">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/baseView">
    </ImageView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/adUnitId"
        tools:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/bView"
        android:background="@color/clear"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.56">
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/target"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pointer"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/shake"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filler1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.35">

        </TextView>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/dark_background"
            android:popupBackground="@color/light_background"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            tools:textColor="@color/myWhite"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
         />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried to reorder the layout but all that acts as expected. Putting the adview first makes it disappear under the imageview (expected). The code waits for a little while before displaying the ad (loadAd). If I don't load the ad, the button stays fine.  If the ad takes a half-second to load next one, the button appears briefly.

Has anyone seen this behavior anywhere? Any suggestions on how to approach? This may only be an issue on this device but how is that possible and how would I know?

Thank you.

Edit: I found another app on the Play Store that exhibits this same behavior when spinning a button only on the ASUS MeMo Pad 7 LTE. I've found a few spinning button apps that appear to work fine.

I've tried many different layout files but no matter what level I put the Ad on it still makes the button disappear after I rotate it. I've tried animation utils (RotateAnimation) as well as 9 old android libraries. No difference.

PROGRESS (but no fix)-: It seems that if I do not animate the button, it stays visible. I'm assuming that something in the animation code is interacting with the button's Z level when the Ad shows up. As soon as I start the animation (either by clicking or rotating the device) the button disappears. (sigh)

Comment: `Show layout bound` and `Layout Insperctor` will help you.

Comment: Azizbekian - thanks for the tip. Both are very useful tools that I hadn't found yet. Unfortunately, the layout bounds show everything to be in the right place with nothing on top of my button.  The layout inspector took a great snapshot that looks normal while the screen of the ASUS MemoPad 7 shows no button (flickers occasionally as soon as the ad appears. Before the ad appears, the button acts normally but you can see the empty space where the ad will go. I'm trying nested RelativeLayouts keeping the ad under the button layout with the same behavior. A real head scratch-er - maybe ASUS bug?

Comment: UPDATE:  I've found two compass programs. One acts the same as mine, one works fine. As soon as the ad appears, the bad one's pointer goes away and flickers just like my app. Any help on how to approach is appreciated.

Comment: Post a screenshot, better in "show layout bounds" mode.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching on related issues, I found how to stop the flickering/disappearing button when Admob shows up using:

```
adView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

See [this answer from 2014.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166636/distorted-ui-onreceive-of-admob-ads)

Hope this helps.